# Remove spaces in Json keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have my json in the below format

```
[{
    "Id": "ALFKI",
    "Contact Name": "Maria Anders",
    "Contact Title": "Sales Representative",
    "City": "Berlin",
    "Slider": 10
}, {
    "Id": "ANATR",
    "Contact Name": "Ana Trujillo",
    "Contact Title": "Owner",
    "City": "México D.F.",
    "Slider": 5
}]
```

**My desired Json**

```
[{
    "Id": "ALFKI",
    "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
    "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
    "City": "Berlin",
    "Slider": 10
}, {
    "Id": "ANATR",
    "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo",
    "ContactTitle": "Owner",
    "City": "México D.F.",
    "Slider": 5
}]
```

Kendo grid doesn't accept Key names with spaces

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: As shown in the desired Json. With no spaces in the keys

Comment: Please show what you've tried and then we can help you fix your code.

Comment: You've told us the problem, but this isnt a code-writing service. You're expected to at least have a try yourself first.

Comment: why don't you create the json correctly at the source

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`, `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\s(?=\w+":)/g` to match space character followed by one or more word characters followed by `"` followed by `:`

```js
var arr = [{
    "Id": "ALFKI",
    "Contact Name": "Maria Anders",
    "Contact Title": "Sales Representative",
    "City": "Berlin",
    "Slider": 10
}, {
    "Id": "ANATR",
    "Contact Name": "Ana Trujillo",
    "Contact Title": "Owner",
    "City": "México D.F.",
    "Slider": 5
}];

arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/\s(?=\w+":)/g, ""));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Just a reminder that it works only on JSON. Any object with a function or a Date object as a value wouldn't work.